# Dual-keyed map without additional data, is it possible?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let's assume that we have a huge map where each element need to be accessed by 2 different keys, `K1` and `K2`. We have both `K1` and `K2` when we add data to the tree, but we need to retrieve data using either `K1` or `K2`. This means both `K1 and K2=ignored` and `K1=ignored and K2` while retrieving data refer to the data defined by `K1 and K2`. Is it possible to do this with a correct comparison method, without duplicating data or using secondary map for showing relationship between `K1` and `K2` (because these 2 methods are obvious but both need to secondary data)? What about hash maps? Because hash maps need both comparison and hash methods.

Comment: Any specific datatypes for the keys?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya I think it is not important algorithm-wise but you can assume that keys(`K1` and `K2`) are positive integer values. it is obvious that you are free to design any data structure to use as your key based on `K1` and `K2` if you don't duplicate data.

Comment: Can you derive `K1` from `K2` or vice versa? Do you know what you're looking at a `K1` or `K2` given some key `k`? Can you have two maps, one from `K1 -> K2`, the other `K2 -> data`?

Comment: @Welbog I cannot derive `K1` from `K2`. When I want to retrieve based on `K1`, I set `K2` to a fixed generic non-key value(for example if keys are positive integers, I can use `0` as fixed generic non-key value when retrieving data). As I mentioned in my post, you can easily do this by using a secondary map showing relationship `K1 -> K2`, but I prefer not to do so if possible. Because using 2nd map practically doubles search time and increases required space for your data structure. In addition, management will complex because you need to keep both maps in similar valid state.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this the following way.

Lets say you maintain a single Map <Key,Value> `map` to store your info.

Now, you when you want to store 2 keys `K1` and `K2` to a value. Store it in a hierarchial form with a parent-child relationship between `K1` and `K2`.

For, example, the map structure would look like this.

```
K1 - Value
K2 - <child_of_identifier>K1
```

So, whenver you want to query using `K1` or `K2`, you can do the following:

```
if(map.exists(key)){
   if(map.get(key).startsWith("<child_of_identifier>"){
       // Parse parent key value
       return map.get(parent_key)
   }else{
       return map.get(key);
   }
}
```

About the solution:

- Does not duplicate data
- Does not have another auxillary map
- Two lookups for child keys
- Flat storage of keys instead of merging 2 keys.

Comment: Hi. I have thought about something similar, but there is a huge drawback for this method. Since you add 2 entries per value to you map, your only has a consistent state when all 2 keys are available. Meaning when you want to add or remove entry which happens in 2 steps(I mean adding 2 keys), you always have a invalid state between these 2. This may lead to invalid map if you cannot add 2nd key for any reason. There are ways to even improve your method(for example allocate data on memory and keep a pointer to that data for value of `K1` and `K2`, so you will find data by 1 lookup).

Comment: For the question, I was more interested in a idea of calculating a key parameter based on `K1` and `K2` which can be used as as real key in a way that this value can be generated with either `K1` or `K2` uniquely for retrieving data.

Comment: Yup. Even I was thinking if there were other key calculation methods. But they would fail on certain generics!